# Use Expo iOS app to test pure react native code

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I want to be able to test an app created with `react-native init` through the expo app downloaded from the app store. How can I do this?

I'm trying to use pure react native (no expo at all) and want to test my code on my iOS device. A while ago, I was able to do this through the expo app simply by running `npm start`. However, now when I run `npm start` I only see `Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a project created with `react-native init` with the Expo app. However, you can use https://snack.expo.io/ to test plain React Native code in either the browser emulator or on your device (which will open through the Expo app) by pointing your iOS camera app at the QR code they display for you. The caveat to this is that you cannot use native modules within a Snack.

Depending on the size of your app, you can port your code over from `react-native init` into a freshly created expo project. I have managed to do this on several projects in the past with great success. The process can be tedious depending on the age of your dependencies however.